# Where is null coming from in this array?

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am converting a php array into xml with something like this :

```
$bigArray = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->formatOutput = true;       
  $r = $doc->createElement( "DATA" );
  $doc->appendChild( $r );     
  foreach( $bigArray as $product )
  {
    $b = $doc->createElement( "ITEM" );        
    $product_type = $doc->createElement( "PRODUCT_TYPE" );
    $product_type->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $product['ProductType'] )
    );
    $b->appendChild( $product_type ); 
    $sku = $doc->createElement( "SKU" );
    $sku->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $product['SKU'] )
    );
    $b->appendChild( $sku ); 
    $r->appendChild( $b );
   }

  echo $doc->saveXML();
```

This returns an xml doc however at the very end null is being appended and I think that is what is causing me other problems.  So for example at the bottom of the xml that is output it looks like :

```
  </ITEM>
</DATA>
null
```

This null value is coming from the original array I see if I do:

```
print_r($bigArray)
```

I see something like :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ProductType] => simple [SKU] => 09423100010018 ) [1] => Array ( [ProductType] => simple [SKU] => 14552300010002 )) null
```

I am calling this from a class in magento like :

```
class Foo_Model_Queryone extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{

    public function pprQuery() {
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');    
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');    
    $query = ("SELECT cpe.type_id AS 'ProductType',
      cpe.sku AS 'SKU',
      .....
```

Comment: Does your script end after `echo $doc->saveXML();`?  I've never had `saveXML()` randomly through a `null` out...especially with no sort of other error

Comment: yes that is the end of that script.  I am running this from a class inside of a Magento model.. maybe that is why it is funky

Comment: I think it's more likely that this `null` is outputted by another class higher up in the inheritance hierarchy, i.e. from test/debug code in a class you are extending.

Comment: Ahh yes thanks Marco.  You are totally right, I didnt think to look there.  I got if fixed.. you can answer or I will just delete this as kind of a sucky question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Class Mage_Core_Model_Abstract is causing the problem, or another class higher up, that is outputting the null value.

Try to step through it using Xdebug in Netbeans, and see what is causing the null value. I am interested to see the outcome.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, yes Marco tipped me off that it must have been something higher up.  It was actually a bug in the controller that I was calling this model from.

Comment: OK, I am glad you found the bug!!